# Loop to go through a list of values

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a macro which goes through a column on my master spreadsheet, then exports all the rows where the value input at the start matches the value in the column. It then saves the new worksheet as the value. Here is the code I currently have:

```
  Option Explicit

Public Const l_HeaderRow As Long = 2 'The header row of the data sheet
Public Const l_DistanceCol As Long = 5 'The column containing the distance values

Public Sub ExportDistance()
Dim ws_Data As Worksheet, wb_Export As Workbook, ws_Export As Worksheet
Dim l_InputRow As Long, l_OutputRow As Long
Dim l_LastCol As Long
Dim l_NumberOfMatches As Long
Dim s_Distance As String, l_Distance As Long
Dim s_ExportPath As String, s_ExportFile As String, s_PathDelimiter As String

    Set ws_Data = ActiveSheet

    s_Distance = InputBox("Enter Distance to Export to New File", "Enter Distance")
    If s_Distance = "" Then Exit Sub
    l_Distance = CLng(s_Distance)
    l_NumberOfMatches = WorksheetFunction.Match(l_Distance, ws_Data.Columns(5), 0)
    If l_NumberOfMatches <= 0 Then Exit Sub

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    Call Application.Workbooks.Add
    Set wb_Export = Application.Workbooks(Application.Workbooks.Count)
    Set ws_Export = wb_Export.Worksheets(1)
    Call wb_Export.Worksheets("Sheet2").Delete
    Call wb_Export.Worksheets("Sheet3").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    ws_Export.Name = GetNextSheetname(ws_Data.Name & "-" & s_Distance, wb_Export)

    Call ws_Data.Rows(1).Resize(l_HeaderRow).Copy
    Call ws_Export.Rows(1).Resize(l_HeaderRow).Select
    Call ws_Export.Paste

    l_OutputRow = l_HeaderRow + 1
    l_LastCol = ws_Data.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    For l_InputRow = l_HeaderRow + 1 To ws_Data.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If ws_Data.Cells(l_InputRow, l_DistanceCol).Value = l_Distance Then

            Call ws_Data.Range(ws_Data.Cells(l_InputRow, 1), ws_Data.Cells(l_InputRow, l_LastCol)).Copy
            Call ws_Export.Rows(l_OutputRow).Select
            Call ws_Export.Paste

            l_OutputRow = l_OutputRow + 1
        ElseIf ws_Data.Cells(l_InputRow, l_DistanceCol).Value = l_Distance Then

            Call ws_Data.Range(ws_Data.Cells(l_InputRow, 1), ws_Data.Cells(l_InputRow, l_LastCol)).Copy
            Call ws_Export.Rows(l_OutputRow).Select
            Call ws_Export.Paste

            l_OutputRow = l_OutputRow + 1
        End If

    Next l_InputRow

    s_ExportPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
    s_PathDelimiter = Application.PathSeparator
    If Right(s_ExportPath, 1) <> s_PathDelimiter Then s_ExportPath = s_ExportPath & s_PathDelimiter
    s_ExportPath = s_ExportPath & "Output" & s_PathDelimiter
    If Dir(s_ExportPath) = Empty Then
        Call MkDir(s_ExportPath)
    End If

    Select Case Application.DefaultSaveFormat
        Case xlOpenXMLWorkbook
            s_ExportFile = s_Distance & ".xlsx"
        Case xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
            s_ExportFile = s_Distance & ".xlsm"
        Case xlExcel12
            s_ExportFile = s_Distance & ".xlsb"
        Case xlExcel8
            s_ExportFile = s_Distance & ".xls"
        Case xlCSV
            s_ExportFile = s_Distance & ".csv"
        Case Else
            s_ExportFile = s_Distance
    End Select
    Call wb_Export.SaveAs(Filename:=s_ExportPath & s_ExportFile, FileFormat:=Application.DefaultSaveFormat)

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub


Public Function GetNextSheetname(s_Name As String, Optional wb_Book As Workbook) As String
Dim l_FIndex  As Long
Dim s_Target As String
    If wb_Book Is Nothing Then Set wb_Book = ActiveWorkbook
    s_Name = Left(s_Name, 31)
    If IsValidSheet(wb_Book, s_Name) Then
        l_FIndex = 1
        s_Target = Left(s_Name, 27) & " (" & l_FIndex & ")"

        Do While IsValidSheet(wb_Book, s_Target)
            l_FIndex = l_FIndex + 1
            If l_FIndex < 10 Then
                s_Target = Left(s_Name, 27) & " (" & l_FIndex & ")"
            ElseIf l_FIndex < 100 Then
                s_Target = Left(s_Name, 26) & " (" & l_FIndex & ")"
            ElseIf l_FIndex < 1000 Then
                s_Target = Left(s_Name, 25) & " (" & l_FIndex & ")"
            End If
        Loop
        GetNextSheetname = s_Target
    Else
        GetNextSheetname = s_Name
    End If
End Function


Public Function IsValidSheet(wbSearchBook As Workbook, v_TestIndex As Variant) As Boolean
Dim v_Index As Variant
On Error GoTo ExitLine
    v_Index = wbSearchBook.Worksheets(v_TestIndex).Name
    IsValidSheet = True
    Exit Function

ExitLine:
    IsValidSheet = False
End Function
```

Please will you help me make this loop through a list of values, rather than my having manually to run the macro each time and input the value myself?

Answer (score 0):

Download this [example here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByXxMRXssekcVkQ2WWVpVUVpX3M/view?usp=sharing).

This is a simple example of how to loop through one range and loop through another range to find the values.
It loops through Column D and then loops through column A, when it finds a match it does something, so basically Column D has taken the place of your inputbox.

[image]

run the macro

[image]

The code

```
Sub DblLoop()

    Dim aLp As Range    'column A
    Dim dLp As Range, dRw As Long    'column D
    Dim d As Range, a As Range


    Set aLp = Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23)
    dRw = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    Set dLp = Range("D2:D" & dRw)

    'start the loop
    'loops through column D and finds value
    'in column A, and does something with it

    For Each d In dLp.Cells    'loops through column D
        For Each a In aLp.Cells    'loops through column A

            If d = a Then
                'When a match, then do something
                'this is where your actual code would go
                Range("A" & a.Row & ":B" & a.Row).Copy Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Offset(1)

            End If
        Next a    'keeps going through column A
    Next d    'next item in column D


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks very much, i'll give it a try and will see how I go with it